# module 'simplekml' has no attribute 'Kml'

Tags: python, simplekml

I am using Python3.6.5 and installed with simplekml module 1.3.3, But there is an error message when I running the code below;
Error msg>>"kml = simplekml.Kml() AttributeError: module 'simplekml' has no attribute 'Kml'"

I am using sample code from https://pypi.org/project/simplekml/

```
import simplekml
#from simplekml import Kml  # this line of code not working either.
kml = simplekml.Kml()
kml.newpoint(name="Kirstenbosch", coords=[(18.432314,-33.988862)])
kml.save("botanicalgarden.kml")
```

Comment: I just installed simplekml and I dont get the error you did.  Maybe try uninstall and reinstall simplekml

Comment: Try `from simplekml import *` and if you use `from simplekml import Kml` you must use this code `kml = Kml() # Not simplekml.Kml()`. And if both are not working, look like something wrong here.

Comment: Notice one file created call **simplekml.cpython-36.pyc** in  **__pycache__** folder. when right click open **simplekml.cpython-36.pyc** then the kml generated.

Comment: found a solution, just put the **.py**  in less sub level, then problem solved. My previous error only occurs in 5th sub folder.